# Typing gs Won't Run GhostScript CentOS

Tags: centos, ghostscript

I followed the steps of compiling the source code of GhostScript on Centos v6. It appears to be straight forward:

1) Download the PDL.tar.gz

```
wget http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/ghostpdl-9.16.tar.gz
```

2) Extract tar.gz

```
tar xvfz ghostpdl-9.16.tar.gz
```

3) cd into the directory and configure

```
cd ghostpdl-9.16
./configure
```

4) Make runs for a 10 minutes or so, says done

```
  make
```

5) Make install....

```
 make install
```

The following is printed back to me in the console

```
install main/obj/pcl6 /usr/local/bin
```

However, I typically open GhostScript by typing gs, why does this not work anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've built the top level PDL (which includes PCL and XPS) but you haven't built Ghopstscript.

For historical reasons (whcih will eventually be done away with) Ghostscript is built separately. Go to ghostpdl-916/gs and repeat the steps from ./configure onwards.